# R - find highest number of repeated digits in a single number

Tags: r

Is there a function that could return the highest number of *sequentially* repeated digits for a given number?

Desired output is the 'Num_repeats' portion for the numbers below:

```
Number                     Num_repeats
18.25328700000000026193    9
18.09606604359100042883    3
17.95982782048729065186    0
```

Comment: do you have a character column in 'Number'

Comment: No -- number is a numeric column in my dataset

Comment: okay, then it would be difficult to replicate the precision of digits you can convert to character with `as.character` and use `strsplit`

Comment: yes, I'm realizing that now sadly -- otherwise your solution was perfect!

Comment: if I consider it numeric, the values would change on my system.  It is better to use `dput` to show the example

Answer (score 1):

If it is a character column, we can split with `strsplit` and use `rle` to extract the `length` of adjacent repeated elements and use `max` to return the `max`` value

```
df1$Num_repeats <- sapply(strsplit(df1$Number, "[.]|"),
           function(x) with(rle(x), max(lengths)))
df1$Num_repeats[df1$Num_repeats==1] <- 0
df1
#                    Number Num_repeats
#1 18.25328700000000026193           9
#2 18.09606604359100042883           3 
#3 17.95982782048729065186           0
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(Number = c("18.25328700000000026193", 
     "18.09606604359100042883", 
"17.95982782048729065186")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution

```
df <- within(df,
             Num_repeats <- sapply(gsub("\\D","",Number,perl = TRUE),
                                   function(x) (u<-max(rle(utf8ToInt(x))$lengths))*(u>1)))
```

or a simpler one

```
df <- within(df,
             Num_repeats <- sapply(Number,
                                   function(x) (u<-max(rle(utf8ToInt(x))$lengths))*(u>1)))
```

such that

```
> df
                   Number Num_repeats
1 18.25328700000000026193           9
2 18.09606604359100042883           3
3 17.95982782048729065186           0
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Number = c("18.25328700000000026193", "18.09606604359100042883", 
"17.95982782048729065186")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think this can be simplified a bit since there won't be two repeating dots: `sapply(x, function(i) {tmp <- max(rle(utf8ToInt(i))$lengths); tmp * (tmp > 1) })`